# PhoneGap cordova external hosts issue

Tags: cordova, extjs

I try to run my app on Phonegap (cordova), but I am getting the error about external hosts issue :

```
CordovaOne[14528:2103] ERROR whitelist rejection: url .....
```

But this issues appears even I've updated the "**Cordova.plist**",

Maybe I update in wrong spott somewhere.

The "Cordova.plist" is in "CordovaOne/Resources/Cordova.plist" ..

Not sure what I do wrong here.

Thanks  guys for any advice !

PS: PhoneGap version 1.5.0

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting this error when attempting to access a URL? If so you need to whitelist domains. Simply add a new value to the `ExternalHosts` array in Cordova.plist. This new value should be `<string>*</string>` which is a catch-all for all domains.

Comment: also trying this myself... * or even the explicit domain doesn't work. version 1.8 here

Answer (score -1):

Thats wrong. You must edit the plist from the Project, not the "cordova"-File. The name is "**PhoneGap.plist**".

Comment: i did download today the latest version from the phonegap, and PhoneGap.plist doesn't exist anymore in the package

Comment: You must install the PhoneGap-Framework. Its seems not installed. Then you have really installed PhoneGap and when you have created a new Project (You must select the "PhoneGap"-Framework on creation), the "PhoneGap.plist" must be available in your Project-Directoy.

Comment: In newer versions it is called Cordova.plist (since PhoneGap split a large part of the code-base into Open Source Cordova)